# Conditionals and logic

Tags: logic

When second and third conditional sentences are used, are they logical?

> If he won the lottery, he would buy a new car.

The reality is he is not buying a new car. So we can safely say he hasn't won the lottery, right?

> If he had gone to the event, he would have returned home late last night.

The reality is he returned home early last night. So we can safely say he didn't go to the event, right?

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: Practical logic is usually to an extent [defeasible](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reasoning-defeasible/). So, while it might be tempting to use conditionals to arrive at certain conclusions, defeasibility allows us to undermine certainty. He didn't buy a car? Maybe he won the lottery, but got sued and can't access the funds. He returned home early last night? Maybe he went to the event, but the event was canceled. Our representation of the state of affairs is arguably always incomplete.

Comment: Yes, you're right, because the reality is often quite complicated. But I mean, if we don't take other things into consideration and focus only on the the given conditional sentences and what we have known (the fact that he returned early last night, and the fact that he isn't buying a new car), we can safely make the conclusions I mentioned above, right?

Comment: What are "second and third conditional sentences" ?

Comment: "if P, then Q" is equivalent to "if not-Q, then not-P". See [Contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).